# LL(1) Parsing table with grammar

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar

I'm trying to get LL(1) Parsing Table with grammar below,

```
S -> ( L ) | a
L -> L , S | S
```

I think it has indirect left recursion because of this,

```
L -> S
```

so I change it to,

```
S -> ( L ) | a
L -> L , ( L ) | L , a | ( L ) | a
```

then like this,

```
S -> ( L ) | a
L -> ( L ) L' | aL'
L' -> , ( L ) L' | ,aL' | epsilon
```

with this, I get FIRSTs and FOLLOWs

```
FIRST(S) = { (, a }          FOLLOW(S) = { $ }
FIRST(L) = { (, a }          FOLLOW(L) = { ) }
FIRST(L') = { , , epsilon}   FOLLOW(L') = { ) }
```

But when I draw LL parsing table, It doesn't go to $.

Did I make mistake or misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(My parsing theory is rusty, so I may have made some mistakes here.)*

`L -> S` is part of indirect recursion, but not left recursion. The production can only "expand" into `L ->+ ( L )` or `L ->+ a`, both of which start with a terminal. The only left recursion here is in the production `L -> L , S`. After [removing this direct left recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion#Removing_direct_left_recursion), I end up with the following grammar:

```
S -> ( L ) | a
L -> S L'
L' -> , S L' | ε
```

With this, the `FIRST` and `FOLLOW` sets you have computed are the same, except that `FOLLOW(S)` is incomplete. Besides `$` (because `S` is the start state), `FOLLOW(S)` must include all elements of `FIRST(L')` (because `L -> S L'` and `L' -> , S L'`) and `FOLLOW(L')` (because `L' -> ε`). I get `FOLLOW(S) = { $, ,, ), ε }`.

The parsing table I get is as follows:

```
    |  (     |  a     |  ,       |  )  |  $  |
----+--------+--------+----------+-----+-----+
S   |  L )   |  a     |          |     |     |
L   |  S L'  |  S L'  |          |     |     |
L'  |        |        |  , S L'  |  ε  |     |
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "it doesn't go to `$`". All I can say is that the column `$` is empty, because all productions of `S` are non-empty and end in a terminal.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for your kind answer!